# Show element where another was without display: none

Tags: html, css

I need an element to appear where another was, let's say on hover for the sake of an example. And I need to use CSS animations to make its transition smoother. So I can't use display property. And instead, I have to use this, right?

```
div {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

But my elements need to overlap, as in where one was, the other has to show instead. With display, that was pretty easy, but with this, I have no clue how to do this without making it too messy.

Can someone help me out? Here's the basic outline of my code:

```css
.first-outline .first:hover {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}
.first-outline .second {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}
.first-outline:hover second {
  visibility: initial;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">

<li class="list-group-item first-outline">
  <p class="first">First</p>
  <p class="second">Second</p>
</li>

<!-- Or something like this, but it still doesn't work -->

<li class="list-group-item second-outline">
  <span class="first">First</span>
  <span class="second">Second</span>
</li>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Check if you are looking for this https://fiddle.jshell.net/mcu7366g/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the container a `positon: relative` and the inner divs `positin: absolute` then play with the hover states and opacity.

add transition property for smooth effect

```css
.first-outline {
  position:relative;
}

.first-outline .first, .first-outline .second {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0 ;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: opacity 500ms linear;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 500ms linear;
  -moz-transition: opacity 500ms linear;
}
  
.first-outline:hover .first, .first-outline .second {
  opacity: 0;
}

.first-outline:hover .second {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">

<li class="list-group-item first-outline">
  <p class="first">First</p>
  <p class="second">Second</p>
</li>
```

Comment: OP: `And I need to use CSS animations to make its transition smoother`

Comment: added transition to snippet